# How does a click-once application determine its application identity?

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a click-once application, which is correctly signed, correctly configured and installs itself without any problem.

It is set to run offline, but install from a specific URL, and if I download and run the setup.exe, it installs updates.

So, it's basically all working... except I cannot print out the version number, or trigger an update from in code. If I try, I get the dreaded: 'Application identity is not set.'

```
2017-01-10 13:43:14.8367 ERROR System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Application identity is not set.
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.get_CurrentDeployment()
   at LibDataAgent.Internal.Services.UpdateService.Deployment() System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Application identity is not set.
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.get_CurrentDeployment()
   at LibDataAgent.Internal.Services.UpdateService.Deployment()
```

I am not running in debug mode, or using a debug build.

So here's my actual question:

How, does the click-once code in `System.Deployment.Application`, at runtime, determine what the application identity is?

So, there are whole lot other questions around this, but please don't close this as a duplicate, as far as I can tell it is not one.

Here's a list of things I *do not* want answers for:

- How to *sign* a click-one application.
- How to *set* the application identity as you build.
- How to find *where* the click-once application is installed.
- How to make a click-once application work while *debugging*.
- How to check for updates using `ApplicationDeployment`.

Just very plainly, *exactly* what does a click-once application do, *at runtime* that lets it determine the application identity.

Help!

#### Notes

My (thus far fruitless) attempts to solve this have yielded these notes:

I'm certain this has something to do with how the application is launched, because executing applications from the command line has never worked with click-once; but executing the same application from the start menu will correctly return `IsNetworkDeployed` as true.

However, I've not been able to determine what the technical difference is, or why one detects the install correctly and one doesn't. (or indeed, why this specific application doesn't work from the start menu, when others with no obvious difference do).

Things I've tried that make no difference include:

- the working directory for the application.
- launching the application .exe directly or via a shell
- launching the application from a new shortcut

There is some kind magic to the 'MyApplication.appref-ms' that goes into the start menu; the appref-ms is just a url to the install path:

```
http://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/blahblah/Dev/MyApplication.application#MyApplication.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fdasdfsafads, processorArchitecture=x86
```

...which *somehow* launches a 'click once aware' instance of the application. But how?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems you cannot test this while debugging. You have to start the Application by the .application-File. The `CurrentDeployment`-Property is only set then. You can check this with `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed`. If this property is false, you are at a dead end it seems

Comment: As I pointed out, I'm not debugging.

Comment: app identity is determined using current AppDomain's ActivationContext property (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.activationcontext.aspx). By default a clickonce app has not the same rights as the deployer app, and the actcontext is null. Have you tried to check "Enable ClickOne security settings" in your project's "Security" tab, recompile and test? of course this can have implications on your whole deployment story (in other words: this is by design in the system)

Comment: @SimonMourier My question is, *how* is the .exe launched in a way that allows the ActivationContext to have a populated identity. How can *I* launch the .exe in this way, *without* invoking internet explorer. Specifically, for example, using the win32 CreateProcess api.

Comment: ie. Specifically *not* how to configure one-click; rather, technically, how is the application launched such that it knows that it has an identity? What is it that DFdll.dll *actually does* that takes .application file, and turns it into a running executable application *with* an identity.

Comment: Do you mean you want to write another exe to update the app? other than that or checking "Enable ClickOnce securty settings" I think it's impossible to do it from the app itself.

Comment: @SimonMourier effectively yes. I want to write a second application that can launch the first application with the correct application identity, without calling DFdll.dll, and without invoking internet explorer. I have no idea what you're talking about with "Enable ClickOnce securty settings"; these settings are obviously already enabled.

Comment: "Enable ClickOnce security settings" is located in the VS project "Security" tab: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z17ceyya.aspx

Comment: Yes. It is selected. That is in no way helpful.

Comment: Do you know the location of your application's manifest file(.application)?

Comment: Ignore the question.Since you use it in your example I assume you do

Comment: _...effectively yes. I want to write a second application that can launch the first application with the correct application identity..._

@Doug, and here I am, in the eve of 2023 trying to do the same .

Answer (score 9):

I'll still happily accept an answer that explains how the guts of launching the application actually sets the application context up with an identity, but for now here's my best stab at what's going on for anyone else who finds this question later:

- ClickOnce applications are launched by hitting the install url, or by using the `.appref-ms` file on the start menu, which contains the url.
- The `application/x-ms-application` MIME type handler is invoked for the downloaded file, which launches the 'ClickOnce aware' instance of the application.
- At runtime, the `ApplicationContext.Identity` is used to determine what the ClickOnce details are, and setup the `CurrentDeployment` object.
- As far as anyone knows, directly launching the deployed executable for a ClickOnce application (in C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\b107ee1... or whatever the install folder is) will **always** return `IsNetworkDeployed` as false, and will not be able to self update.

Practically speaking, this means:

- You're looking for the install folder and path to your .exe? Don't bother. Even when you know where it is, it won't have the correct `ApplicationContext` when you run it.
- To spawn a new 'ClickOnce aware' instance of your application launch internet explorer at its install url. You cannot pass command line arguments to it.

eg.

```
var url = "http://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/blahblah/Dev/MyApplication.application#MyApplication.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fdasdfsafads, processorArchitecture=x86";
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = @"iexplore",
    Arguments = $"\"{url}\"",
};
Process.Start(psi);
```

(if you want to find the URL, hunt through the start menu for the `appref-ms` file for the application; the url is contained in it)

...and how does the executable get launched with an identity?

No idea; but this is as far as anyone seems to ever have got with understanding it:

(tldr; magic. Probably something to do with how CreateProcess is invoked to spawn the appliciation using the ApplicationContext api, in some combination of DFsvc.exe. DFshim.dll and DFdll.dll)

(The rest of this information is taken from this old blog post by Ian Picknel: http://ianpicknell.blogspot.com.au/2010/03/launching-clickonce-application.html)

> Once the deployment manifest has been
>   stored in the Temporary Internet Files folder, Internet Explorer then
>   attempts to establish how it should handle the file with the (assumed
>   and actual) .application extension. It checks the user-specific file
>   types at HKCU\Software\Classes and, if it fails to find an
>   .application sub-key there, checks for machine-specific file types at
>   HKCR. Via this means it establishes that the .application extension
>   denotes an Application.Manifest file. It then uses this information to
>   check the user-specific HKCU\Software\Classes\Application.Manifest and
>   machine-specific HKCR\Application.Manifest keys to establish the CLSID
>   of a library which handles Application.Manifest files and yields the
>   result {98af66e4-aa41-4226-b80f-0b1a8f34eeb4}. Finally, it looks up
>   this CLSID in the user-specific
>   HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID{98af66e4-aa41-4226-b80f-0b1a8f34eeb4} and
>   machine-specific HKCR\CLSID{98af66e4-aa41-4226-b80f-0b1a8f34eeb4}
>   paths to establish that .application files are handled by
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\DFshim.dll.
>
> This is where things start to get a little complicated. I said earlier
>   that no 'magic' was happening behind the scenes. Well, whilst that was
>   true for the process of retrieving the deployment manifest it most
>   certainly is not true of the process of actually launching the
>   ClickOnce application once the deployment manifest has been retrieved
>   and the handler, DFshim.dll, has been identified.
>
> DFshim.dll is described in the registry as the 'Manifest mime handler'
>   although its file properties describe it as the 'Application
>   Deployment Support Library'. It implements the Internet Explorer MIME
>   handler COM interface. It is a native 32-bit DLL, written in Microsoft
>   Visual C++ 2005, and was installed into C:\Windows\system32 when the
>   .NET Framework 2.0 was installed.
>
> DFshim.dll has a hard-coded reference to DFdll.dll, which it locates
>   by checking the values of
>   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\InstallRoot (typically
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework) and the keys beneath
>   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\Policy\AppPatch (typically
>   v2.0.50727, even if a later version of the Framework is installed).
>   DFdll.dll too is a native 32-bit DLL written in Microsoft Visual C++
>   2005.
>
> DFdll.dll uses COM services exposed by DFsvc.exe, which is also
>   located in the .NET Framework folder. DFsvc.exe is a standard .NET
>   MSIL assembly. DFsvc contains a single Main method (within the
>   System.Deployment.Application namespace) which simply calls the
>   internal System.Deployment.Application.DFServiceEntryPoint.Initialize
>   method within System.Deployment.dll. The Initialize method registers
>   System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentServiceCom with COM via
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.RegistrationServices (i.e. it performs
>   the equivalent of CoRegisterClassObject in COM) using the CLSID
>   {33246f92-d56f-4e34-837a-9a49bfc91df3}. This is the means by which its
>   services are made available to DFdll.dll.
>
> The COM service exposed by
>   System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentServiceCom delegates the
>   majority of its methods to other non-ComVisible classes within the
>   System.Deployment.Application namespace. For example, the public
>   ActivateDeployment method calls ActivateDeployment on a new
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator instance, the
>   public CheckForDeploymentUpdate method calls CheckForDeploymentUpdate
>   on System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore, etc.
>
> It is clear that the vast majority of the work surrounding the actual
>   installation and launch of the ClickOnce application is undertaken by
>   classes within the System.Deployment namespace, hosted within
>   DFsvc.exe. DFshim.dll and DFdll.dll appear to primarily be responsible
>   for arbitrating between the COM-based world of Internet Explorer and
>   the .NET-based world of ClickOnce.