# Using ClickOnce API without installation

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, clickonce, auto-update

I have a Winforms application. I have published it using ClickOnce. But my requirement is to use the ClickOnce API in the forms application without installing the published installer on the client side. I found that `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed`property has to be used for this. But every time I run the application, this property returns `false`. I am not able to use any ClickOnce APIs.

Am I missing something? What should I do to use the ClickOnce APIs without installing the application?

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: IsNetworkDeployed returns true only when you are running app from an installed deployment. It's not good practice to override this behaviour.
So the question is "Why exactly you need to set that flag to false?"

Comment: maybe this gives you additional insight: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41562219/4011717

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` will be `true` when the application has been installed on the machine *and* has been started using the .appref-ms reference created by ClickOnce during the installation. Otherwise it is `false`.

There is no way to use the API (i.e. `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment`) without installing the application as there simply is no current deployment available.

Comment: Thanks for the info.